# How to know a file has digital signature attribute

Tags: winapi, digital-signature

Is there any Windows API to know a file has digital signature attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [WinVerifyTrust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388208%28VS.85%29.aspx) API. Here is an [Example C Program on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382384%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Do there is any thing like this in php to check if a file have digital signature

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of threads about this on the sysinternals forum with some good info and examples:

- [HOWTO: Verify digital signature of a file](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=19404)
- [HOWTO: Verify the digital signature of a file](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=19247)
- [SigCheck functionality](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=16893&PID=83634)